# To which releases can I go when I'm on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3

Tags: upgrade, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to upgrade my red hat  to a new release, to which release I can go from the one I'm using?

Comment: Have you checked the Red Hat site?

Comment: Are you running RHEL 3?! With your RHEL subscription you should have also gained some support options direct from Redhat. Check in to https://access.redhat.com/home and get their advice.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in redhat's online documentation (e.g. [RHEL 5](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-upgrade-x86.html), [RHEL 6](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-upgrade-x86.html)) upgrades between major versions of RHEL are not supported; it is best to install RHEL 6 fresh.

Comment: What we are using on an SGI ALTIX3000 is a Linux sgialtix 2.4.21-sgi304r1 #1 SMP Sat Jan 29 22:43:29 PST 2005 ia64 ia64 ia64 GNU/Linux-------------rpm -q redhat-release=redhat-release-3AS-8.3-------------/etc/redhat-release= Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 3)